# Bootstrap 3.0 Max Column Width: 95px or 97.5px?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If you look at the page: [Boostrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), under the Grid Options heading, there’s a table listing the features of the new grid.

I did a small page with 12 columns (with the class of .col-lg-).

In the table, it says that the ‘Max column with’ is 95px (4th row in the table). However, when I inspected a column, the calculated with is 97.5px, but not 95px.

When I measured the column length in Photoshop, they alternate between 98px and 97px (probably due to rounding up the 77.5px).

Highly appreciate if you guys can explain how this difference comes here? Or, does the bootstrap docs refer to something else, when they mention the ‘Max column width’?

(I’m not good with CSS and the grid systems, so apologies if I got something wrong).

Here's the test code I put together:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />  
        <style>
            p {
                background-color: #999
            }   
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-1"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>           
            </div>  
        </div>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js" >
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: So far in Firefox and Chrome. Pretty much the same behavior. Think there's nothing wrong with browsers or bootstrap - Maybe I'm not getting the concept of 'Max column width' right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am on Ubuntu OS. I get the following results.
1. Firefox 98px
2. Chrome 97px

I think 2-3 px difference comes from how the browsers calculate widths.

PS
Same ticket is raised on GitHub
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12808
This issue was corrected and the corrected values have been listed here.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/a083f0deb77dd479a7690a4ab90f73f7f7f375cd

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much Vikram for your reply. So I guess it should be a wrong documentation info. Actually the correct calculated width is 97.5px, since there are no half pixels what so ever, browsers might alternate column widths between 97 and 98 px. For ex: 1st column 98px and the next 97px and the third one again 98px, and so on.

Comment: And I think https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12808 has tackled the problem well. Actually I was trying to do the same thing as him: build up Photoshop grid templates for Botostrap 3.0. Thanks again for clarification. P.S. Do you do bootstrap development?